# XWPFDocument : replace tag with html text

Tags: java, xwpf

In a docx document, I want to replace a tag `<example_tag>`with some html formatted text (bold):

> **Hello world**

I am doing :

```
text = text.replace("<example_tag>", (exp.getComment()!=null?exp.getComment():"Unknown"));
r.setText(text, 0);
```

Here exp.getComment() = `<b>Hello world</b>`

How to display `<b>Hello world</b>`
without displaying the `<b></b>` tags?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace it, like this:

```
 "<b>Hello world</b>".replaceAll("<.*?>", "");
```

Comment: the result : Hello world will not be bold at the end. I would like XWPF to convert it to bold if there is a <b></b>, same for <br> and creating a new line

Comment: Use XWPFRun, and you can do a simple if contains ``<br>`` and   ``word.setBold(true);`` For more information: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi_word/apache_poi_word_font_style

Comment: what if my string looks like : texte A<br><b>test pour voir&nbsp;</b><br><i><u>comment ca rend<br></u></i><br>